# Creating a new series in a chart where the data is in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a chart where the number of series is changing, and all the series are drawing data from different worksheets that isn't the active worksheet. The graph is being created on a main worksheet called "graphsName", the data for each series is on a different sheet, that is renamed "targetSheetName" by a larger sub.

Right now, I have the following:

```
Public Sub GraphingTemperature(ByVal targetSheetName As String, ByVal graphsName As String)

Sheets(graphsName).Select
Application.Run "getUnits"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
     .Name = Sheets(targetSheetName).Range("C1")
    .Values = Sheets(targetSheetName).Range(Range("C5"), Range("C5").End(xlDown))
    .XValues = Sheets(targetSheetName).Range(Range("D5"), Range("D5").End(xlDown))
End With



End Sub
```

This function is being called by a longer sub that made the chart, and is then feeding this function the sheet name that holds the data for that particular series.

I didn't want to use the

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name
```

strcture because the number of series is constantly changing.

It looks like the problem occurs when I am trying to direct it to the values, and xvalues of the series. I would like the chart series to begin at the 5th row of the column and continue to the last entry. Does anyone know the correct syntax for when I want to get a series data from another worksheet and am passing in the name of the worksheet to the sub?

Comment: First step. Don't pass a worksheet name, pass a worksheet variable.

Comment: The problem is that `Range("C5"), Range("C5").End(xlDown)` and `Range("D5"), Range("D5").End(xlDown)` - you need to qualify the worksheet these ranges are on.

Comment: I think I qualify the worksheet the ranges are on with "Sheets(targetSheetName)" prior to the range? When I run the macro, the chart is able to be created with the correct name from c1 in the targetSheetName worksheet, so I think it is getting the correct worksheet. The problem arises when I try to get the x and y values

Comment: Nope - the `Range` calls inside the parentheses are implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Basically `Sheets(targetSheetName).Range(Range("C5"), Range("C5").End(xlDown))` is equivalent to `Sheets(targetSheetName).Range(ActiveSheet.Range("C5"), ActiveSheet.Range("C5").End(xlDown))`.

Comment: Ah okey, I changed it to ```.Values = Sheets(targetSheetName).Range(Sheets(targetSheetName).Range("C5"), Sheets(targetSheetName).Range("C5").End(xlDown))
    .XValues = Sheets(targetSheetName).Range(Sheets(targetSheetName).Range("D5"), Sheets(targetSheetName).Range("D5").End(xlDown))``` and it works now, thank you!